# How do node operations affect TWCS SSTables?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

There are a couple of documents and articles online that suggest turning off read repair for tables using the time window compaction strategy (TWCS), as it mixes data that should belong to old buckets into new ones, which leads to higher read amplification.

I wonder if some common node operations will cause similar things.
Specifically, adding a node, replacing a dead node, running `nodetool repair`, running `nodetool decommission` or running `nodetool rebuild`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely disable repairs for TWCS tables and don't run any manual repairs either. The reason is that a repair will not place the inconsistent data in the old bucket, but will instead drop the mutation into the current bucket. This means that the current bucket's sstables will not be able to drop until that particular mutation is able to drop due to the TTL expiring.

In regard to adding/removing nodes, each sstable file contains the max timestamp for each sstable in the metadata, and so on
streaming (adding/removing nodes) sstables are added to their
correct and expected windows.

Comment: I wonder how not running any sort of repair at all is practical advice. Isn't repair needed in a table using TWCS needed for the same reason it is needed in any other table? I guess that certain practices - like enabling hinted-handoff and making sure the GC grace period is higher than the TWCS window - make not doing repair less of a problem, but I am not sure how we can be sure that we can forgo any repair, ever.